Input file html to python function
На html странице есть инпут файла. Как его можно передать с помощью ванильного js-а или как-то по другому в питоновскую функцию.(если вообще такое возможно)

Отправить обычную форму. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data#%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2

да, Вы можете передать файл с HTML-формы в Python, используя JS
<form id="fileForm">
    <input type="file" id="fileInput" name="file">
    <button type="button" onclick="uploadFile()">Upload File</button>
</form>

    <script>
        function uploadFile() {
            const fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
            const file = fileInput.files[0];

            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('file', file);

            // Отправляем запрос на сервер
            fetch('/upload', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData
            })
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(result => {
                console.log('Success:', result);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            });
        }
    </script>

